# Pass a current $row value to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, variables, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Works At</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Initial</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>SSN#</th>
                <th>Modify</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM employees";

            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

            foreach ($stmt as $row): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['rest_id_employees']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['minit']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['start_date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ssn']; ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?ssn='.urlencode($row['ssn']); ?>#delModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#editModal"><i class="icon-wrench icon-white"></i> Edit</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

My goal is to pass the value of $row['ssn'] into my #delModal. I assume the problem lies within:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?ssn='.urlencode($row['ssn']); ?>#delModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a>
```

It is my understanding that with the above syntax I should be able to use `$_GET['ssn']` inside the Bootstrap Modal to pull the value, but when I `var_dump($ssn)` the value only `NULL` is printed.

Here is the Modal:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="delModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 style="color: red">WARNING</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
                $ssn = $_GET['ssn'];
                var_dump($ssn);
            ?>
            <h4>You are about to delete --- from your Employee database.</h4>
            <p>An employee cannot be recoverd once they have been deleted. They can be added to the system again, but
                all data about the employee will be lost if you delete them. Are you sure you mean to delete this
                employee from the database?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteemployee.php?ssn=<?php echo urlencode($ssn); ?>"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The overall purpose of this implementation is to use the Modal as a means to not accidentally delete an employee by prompting the user with a warning. I cannot just use `$row` within the Modal as it will pull the last row every time, and I'm sure there's a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do than what I'm trying to do here, but I'm not sure what that way is.

Comment: Hmmm - your code seems to work for me.. Are you sure $row['ssn'] has a valid value - have you tried without urlencode?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Rather than passing value as get directly echo your values in model, and get an advantage of both being in same file.

**call your model like this**

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#delModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a>
```

**In model try like this**

```
<div class="modal hide" id="delModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 style="color: red">WARNING</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
            <?php echo $row['ssn']; ?>
        <h4>You are about to delete --- from your Employee database.</h4>
        <p>An employee cannot be recovered once they have been deleted. They can be added to the system again, but
            all data about the employee will be lost if you delete them. Are you sure you mean to delete this
            employee from the database?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteemployee.php?ssn=<?php echo urlencode($ssn); ?>"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you pass the parameter? Where did you put the parameter in? I have multiple Delete Icons, each one passing a unique parameter to the modal.

Answer (score 3):

Hello I had the same issue and almost the same code as you are using. But I able to solve that issue later by passing my parameter value as href id.

I had a button named READ, to open my model window. Here is the HTML code for my button.

```
<a button type="button" href="#<?php echo''.$u_id.'';?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary"> READ  </a>
```

Here in that above code, you can see i have used id(column name and the primary key) of the message as the href id!

And here is the my code for **MODEL WINDOW**

```
<div class="modal" id="<?php echo''.$u_id.'';?>">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Create public Event</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

    <?php echo '.$u_id.';?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so once I passed the id (parameter) in to the modal, I can get other values using simple sql query.

So for your code also, i'm suggesting you to pass your primary key column value (Eg:id) as the button href id and div id.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use Jquery Ajax call 
like the following step: -
 1. Create a function which get a parameter (or more). 
 2. Which is use to process Ajax post method.
 3. And on return print HTML data in the modal div.
 4. Call that function along with modal button "onClick" event...

And rest will be done easily the best and simple way to do that

http://infotonicsmedia.com

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a simular situation.
My solution was:

```
private function pri_show_weekcontent($p_sCourse){ 

for($iWeekcounter=1;$iWeekcounter<=10;$iWeekcounter++){ 
// Fetch the nesseray data from the database       
    $aCellContent = $this->fetchAssignmentscontents($p_sCourse,$iWeekcounter);
// Create an unique ID for the modal, in my case course+weeknumber
    echo("<div id='".$p_sCourse.$iWeekcounter."' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>");
// Build the modal
    echo("<div class='modal-dialog'>");
        echo("<div class='modal-content'>");
          echo("<div class='modal-header'>");
            echo("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>");
            echo("<h4 class='modal-title'>Toelichting opdracht</h4>");
          echo("</div>");
          echo("<div class='modal-body'>");
// show the content from the database
            echo("<p>".$aCellContent[0][6]."</p>");
          echo("</div>");
          echo("<div class='modal-footer'>");
            echo("<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>");
          echo("</div>");
        echo("</div>");
      echo("</div>");
    echo("</div>");

    if(!empty($aCellContent)){
        if($_SESSION['verifiedUser']=='true'){echo("<td align='center' width='8%' bgcolor='white'><a href='editassignment.php?rn=".$aCellContent[0][0]."'><span title='".$aCellContent[0][6]."'>".$aCellContent[0][5]."</span></a></td>"); }
// call the unique ID model with a click.           
        else{echo("<td align='center' width='8%' bgcolor='white'><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#".$p_sCourse.$iWeekcounter."'>".$aCellContent[0][5]."</a></td>");}
    }else{
        if($_SESSION['verifiedUser']=='true'){echo("<td align='center' width='8%' bgcolor='lightgreen'><a href='addassignment2.php?cn=".$_SESSION['sClassname']."&oo=".$p_sCourse."&pn=".$_SESSION['iPeriodNumber']."&wn=".$iWeekcounter."'>Geen huiswerk</a></td>");}
        else{echo("<td align='center' width='8%'>&nbsp;</td>");}
    }        
}
```

}